# Direct vs indirect object pronoun forms

Tags: pronouns

I understand that it would be trivial to ask whether or not English *has* object pronouns classifiable as either direct or indirect - this is a matter of grammatical structure.

My question is whether there are different *forms* for direct or indirect object pronouns, or if both modes are identically represented by the same 'object pronouns' (me, you, him, her, it, us, you, them)?

Comment: Why would you think there are different forms? English certainly doesn't have a separate case for indirect objects.

Comment: @alphabet didn't care much for a formal understanding of grammar when i was younger + i am learning french now so i need to clarify a lot of the english classifications :/
thank you, that seems to be the answer i need

Comment: Are you referring to personal pronouns or pronouns in general?

Comment: @BillJ pronouns in general

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @BillJ checking various linguistic dictionaries and wikipedia pages. i was having trouble finding the exact phrase "English doesn't have a separate case for indirect objects" as alphabet supplied above

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Comment: Can you Post a few examples?